# Binding MXML CSS value

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

In some of my containers I want to bind the padding and gap value to a variable so they are consistent throughout my application and I have the following code

```
  <s:VGroup gap="{MyCSSStyle.space}"
            paddingLeft="{MyCSSStyle.space}"
            paddingRight="{MyCSSStyle.space}"
            paddingTop="{MyCSSStyle.space}"
            paddingBottom="{MyCSSStyle.space}">
```

However it is not good if I have to copy the inline styles everywhere, is it possible to bind the values in CSS such that I can achieve like this?

```
    .myStyle {
            gap: {MyCSSStyle.space};
            paddingLeft: {MyCSSStyle.space};
            paddingRight: {MyCSSStyle.space};
            paddingTop: {MyCSSStyle.space};
            paddingBottom: {MyCSSStyle.space};
    }
    <s:VGroup styleName="myStyle">
```

I tried but the complier do not allow me to do binding like that.

Comment: But why you need like that. use same style for all instead.

Comment: Because the style value required to be dynamic, such that I can config the value in external source like database or config files and see the updated result on the fly.

Comment: then you can set it using actionscript also.

Comment: can you provide example on how?

Comment: like `playBtn.setStyle("paddingLeft",20);`

Comment: Thanks. However I prefer a simpler declarative solution in mxml way, I will take it as answer if extra lines of as3 code is inevitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding of CSS is not possible in flex. Instead you can use actionscript to give css dynamically like following:

**MXML:**

```
<s:VGroup id="vgContainer" />
```

**Script:**

```
vgContainer.setStyle("paddingLeft",MyCSSStyle.space);
vgContainer.setStyle("paddingRight",MyCSSStyle.space);
vgContainer.setStyle("paddingTop",MyCSSStyle.space);
vgContainer.setStyle("paddingBottom",MyCSSStyle.space);
```

Hope, It will help.